# How to click on '+ Add to Friends'

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am trying to click on '+ Add to Friends'.

`browser.div(:class, "+ Add to Friends").click`  and `browser.div(:text, "+ Add to Friends").click`

But get: `Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with`

```
<div data-friend="5004" onclick="return {'b-profileFriendsButton': {'friend': '5004' }}" class=" b-profileFriendsButton_mode_0 i-bem b-profileFriendsButton_js_inited">
<div class="b-profileFriendsButton__text b-profileFriendsButton__text_mode_2">Friends</div>
<div class="b-profileFriendsButton__hover b-profileFriendsButton__hover_mode_2 b-profileFriendsButton__deleteFromFriends">– Delete From Friends</div>
<div class="b-profileFriendsButton__text b-profileFriendsButton__text_mode_1">Friends</div>
<div class="b-profileFriendsButton__hover b-profileFriendsButton__hover_mode_1 b-profileFriendsButton__deleteFromFriends">– Delete From Friends</div>
<div class="b-profileFriendsButton__text b-profileFriendsButton__text_mode_0 b-profileFriendsButton__addToFriends">+ Add to Friends</div>
<div class="b-profileFriendsButton__hover b-profileFriendsButton__hover_mode_0 b-profileFriendsButton__addToFriends">+ Add to Friends</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no <div> tag with a class attribute of "+ Add to Friends", so `browser.div(:class, "+ Add to Friends").click` shouldn't work at all. To use a `:class` locator in this case, you'd do something like this:

```
browser.div(:class, "b-profileFriendsButton__text b-profileFriendsButton__text_mode_0 b-profileFriendsButton__addToFriends").click
```

And there are 2 <div> tags containing a "+ Add to Friends" text string, so a compound locator using `:text` and `:index` should help identify the correct one.  For example:

```
browser.div(:text => "+ Add to Friends", :index => 0).click
```

Lastly, try using the [`when_present`](http://rdoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/EventuallyPresent#when_present-instance_method) method to wait for page elements to become fully enabled:

```
browser.div(:text => "+ Add to Friends", :index => 0).when_present.click
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
browser.div(:class => "b-profilePage__button").click

browser.div(:class => "b-profileFriendsButton__hover b-profileFriendsButton__hover_mode_0 b-profileFriendsButton__addToFriends").click
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.
Since we have two +Add to friends. Use Regular expression and index properties to click.

```
browser.div(:class=>/addToFriends/, :index=>0).click
browser.div(:class=>/addToFriends/, :index=>1).click
```